# Change style on only one <li> element when clicking it

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have an assignment in uni to do a grocery list in only HTML and javascript. And when I click on a li element it is supposed to change style to line-through. But when i tried to do this all li elements got the line-through instead of only the one i clicked on. I've tried for a long time to fix this and now my code doesn't work at all..Please help me

**This is my HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Inköpslista</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Inköpslista</h2>
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Ange vara..."/>
    <button onclick="nyttElement()">Lägg till</button>
    </div>

    <ul id="myUL">
        <li>Kakor</li>
        <li>Bullar</li>
        <li style="text-decoration: line-through;">Nutella</li>
     </ul>
    <script src="lista.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**This is the javascript** to add a new li element to my list:

```
function nyttElement(){
    var newItem = document.createElement("li");
    var item = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(item);
    newItem.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(newItem);
}
```

And this works fine until I try to add the `eventListener`:

```
document.getElementById("myUL").addEventListener("click", function{
    var selectLi = document.querySelectorAll("li") 
    for (var i =0; i < selectLi.length; i++){
        selectLi[i].style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        selectLi[i].style.color = "red";
    }

    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well your code explicitly fetches *all* the `<li>` elements and changes all of them, so it's not surprising that it does what you're complaining about.

Comment: "But when i tried to do this all li elements got the line-through instead of only the one i clicked on." The item you clicked on is it newly added or hard coded?

Comment: I presume you are trying event delegation. Please go through https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the click event to the `ul` element and to check if the clicked element using the `event.target` keyword.

**NOTE:** You may need to prevent the empty fields from submitting using:

```
if (item !== "") {
     //Append the 'li'
}
```

```js
document.querySelector("#myUL").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    e.target.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    e.target.style.color = "red";
  }
});

function nyttElement() {
  var item = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

  if (item !== "") {
    var newItem = document.createElement("li");
    var text = document.createTextNode(item);

    newItem.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(newItem);
  } else {
    console.log('Some message in the else clause about filling the empty field.')
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Inköpslista</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Inköpslista</h2>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Ange vara..." />
    <button onclick="nyttElement()">Lägg till</button>
  </div>

  <ul id="myUL">
    <li>Kakor</li>
    <li>Bullar</li>
    <li style="text-decoration: line-through;">Nutella</li>
  </ul>
  <script src="lista.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click event listener is for the entire unordered list, and you are iterating through each list item and crossing it out. If you listen for a click event on each individual list item, you can strike out the specific list item that was clicked.

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('#myUL > li')

function addEventListener(li) {
  return li.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.className = this.className == 'todo' ? 'done' : 'todo'
  });
}

function nyttElement(){
  var newItem = document.createElement('li');
  var item = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  newItem.appendChild(text);
  newItem.className = 'todo';
  addEventListener(newItem);
  document.getElementById('myUL').appendChild(newItem);
}

listItems.forEach(li => addEventListener(li))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Inköpslista</title>
<style>
  li.todo {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  li.done {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Inköpslista</h2>
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Ange vara..."/>
    <button onclick="nyttElement()">Lägg till</button>
    </div>

    <ul id="myUL">
        <li class="todo">Kakor</li>
        <li class="todo">Bullar</li>
        <li class="done">Nutella</li>
     </ul>
    <script src="lista.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over all the li.
To highlight clicked li you have to use event deligation as below

```js
function nyttElement() {
  var newItem = document.createElement("li");
  var item = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  newItem.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(newItem);
}


document.getElementById("myUL").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // if target is li
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === 'LI') {
    // toggle done class
    e.target.classList.toggle('done');
  }
});
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Inköpslista</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Inköpslista</h2>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Ange vara..." />
    <button onclick="nyttElement()">Lägg till</button>
  </div>

  <ul id="myUL">
    <li>Kakor</li>
    <li>Bullar</li>
    <li>Nutella</li>
  </ul>
  <!--<script src="lista.js"></script>-->
</body>

</html>
```